# Is the email on my profile, my notification email?

Tags: support, email, email-notification

I want to receive notifications but not list my email on my profile.

I'm searching and looking through meta and the SE site, but I haven't found a clear answer to my question. Thanks in advance.

PS: Another possible related question, is my email hidden on my profile?

Comment: Yes your email address is hidden to normal users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, your email address is hidden; the rest of the data is public except your real name and DOB(Your DOB *is* exposed as your age, though)

That email is the one used to send you notifications. It's usually stolen from the OpenID provider.

Comment: The DOB is exposed as Age on the profile so technically it isn't completely hidden. Nit-picking I know but to be technical.